# Why does postgres allow me to access localhost without any password regardless of role?

Tags: postgresql, password

I was under the impression that Postgres used some local socket magic to allow a local user to access postgres without password, whereas passing the host (`-h`) option would force it to use TCP and thus prompt for a password. This does not seem to be the case:

```
$ command psql -h 127.0.0.1 -W -U sim mydb
Password:
Timing is on.
Line style is unicode.
Border style is 2.
Null display is "[NULL]".
Expanded display is used automatically.
psql (15.3 (Homebrew))
Type "help" for help.

127.0.0.1 sim@mydb=>
```

I force a password prompt, pass localhost as the host and still I can provide whatever password I like: I always get in. I am not sure what happens here, but it is not what I expect.

My intent is to test that I got the password right, to debug some application error, so this behavior is not helpful.

Homebrew install on macOS 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `pg_hba.conf`.  It probably has something like this:

```
local   all    all     peer
```

or this:

```
local   all    all     trust
```

As long as there is a ROLE named `sim`:

- `peer` lets a MacOS user named `sim` connect, and
- `trust` lets `sim` connect no matter what.

Excerpt from [docs on pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> Client authentication is controlled by a configuration file, which traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and is stored in the database cluster's data directory.

Typical locations for `pg_hba.conf` when using Homebrew:

```
$ find /opt -name pg_hba.conf -type f
/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@13/pg_hba.conf
/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12/pg_hba.conf
/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/pg_hba.conf
/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: Indeed you were right. The only thing that is different is that the config has 5 columns, where the missing one relates to the IP+netmask that matches the rule. So this is the one for IPv4: `# IPv4         `
`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust`

Comment: @oligofren because of `-h 127.0.0.1`.  You don't need that argument, though, since Pg also uses a domain socket.